# image download successfully but i open image its show "this file can't be opened. The file might be damaged."

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

```
//this section is download  user image data from the db
@RequestMapping(value={"/downloadRow-{img_id}"} , method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void downloadImageFile(@PathVariable int img_id,HttpServletResponse response ,HttpServletRequest request,ModelMap model) 
throws IOException, ServletRequestBindingException{

    ImageModel imgModel=service.downloadFile(img_id);   
    response.setContentType(imgModel.getImageContentTyepe());
    response.setContentLength(imgModel.getImageContentTyepe().length());
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\""+imgModel.getImg_name()+"\" ");
    FileCopyUtils.copy(imgModel.getImageConent(), response.getOutputStream());              //qustn
    response.getOutputStream().close();
    showRecord(model) ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a

```
response.flushbuffer
```

after you copy the stream. This is working for me:

```
            response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.toString());
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getFileName());
            IOUtils.copy(fsin, response.getOutputStream());
            fsin.close();
            response.flushBuffer();
            response.getOutputStream().close()
```

Comment: then something else is wrong, that download is working as intended for me, is your source file ok? how do you ingest it?